# restrict access to a website to only one machine

Tags: java, security, https

I've got two servers, lets call them server 1 and server 2. There is a web application on server 2, that, lets say, shows posts. This application is available on http://www.2.com/showPosts and everybody can access this page. This application also enables to remotely add posts. To do that you have to go to page http://www.2.com/addPost and fill a form.

What I'd like to do is to restrict access to this second page (/addPost) to only one single machine, that is server 1, so that only I can enter this page and fill this form, and everyone else gets 404. How to accomplish that?

edit:
Thank you for your answers. I've done some more reading based on them and now can make my question a little more precise. What I exactly need to do is to authenticate a client by server, whis is the opposite of one-way ssl authentication, where you authenticate a server by a client. I think that any kind of ip based authentication is way too weak and I need some kind of a certificate.

Comment: I would running it on a different port.  Then you know no other machine can access that port.

Comment: @PeterLawrey unless someone happens to run a port scanner or somehow discovers the address. Then it is back to square one.

Comment: @tucuxi I would hope the OP's web server has some sort of firewall. In which case the second admin port wouldn't be accessible from any machine he/she didn't want.  If they can run a port scanner on the same machine, you are right but I suspect you have real problems if they can.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `.htaccess` file in the root directory:

```
<Directory AddPost>Allow from www.1.com</Directory>
```

This only lets `www.1.com` access the page. If `AddPost` is a file, use `<Files AddPost></Files>`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Protect your *http://www.2.com/addPost* with a cerificate only present in the Browser on the one single machine.

Comment: I thought about certificates, but I've no idea how to handle them. Both apps on server 1 and 2 are Java apps - have you got any idea how should I approach this certificates, maybe some literature or link to webpages?

Comment: A short google-search came up with this, which seams to be what you want (at least on the first look) http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/securitymonkey/howto-securing-a-website-with-client-ssl-certificates-11500

Answer (score 0):

`ServletRequest#getRemoteAddr()` returns you the IP of the client that sent the request. You could filter such requests by matching client's IP. For the other clients you can for example redirect to predefined `404 error` page.

Answer (score 0):

You can also restrict the addPost address to localhost-only, and establish an ssh tunnel for update purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using Apache Web Server, then you can configure a virtual host and set an access rule to deny from all, allow from server1. Here the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html).

Comment: probably the simplest solution so far

Comment: This would work, but this restriction would be based on ip adress, and that's quite easy to bypass

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Tomcat server you can define a filter in web.xml that will filter request only from allowed source.